# How is this #define supposed to be used?

Tags: c

I found the following #define in a header file for an NXP processor:

```
/*! @name GLOBAL - LPUART Global Register */
/*! @{ */
#define LPUART_GLOBAL_RST_MASK                   (0x2U)
#define LPUART_GLOBAL_RST_SHIFT                  (1U)
/*! RST - Software Reset
 *  0b0..Module is not reset.
 *  0b1..Module is reset.
 */
#define LPUART_GLOBAL_RST(x)                     (((uint32_t)(((uint32_t)(x)) << LPUART_GLOBAL_RST_SHIFT)) & LPUART_GLOBAL_RST_MASK)
```

and I wonder how it is supposed to be used. Any explanation will be greatly appreciated.

M'

Comment: That must be somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: (This is a guess.) I presume the value `LPUART_GLOBAL_RST(0)` has the reset bit not set and the value `LPUART_GLOBAL_RST(1)` has the reset bit set and that the value (perhaps bitwise-ORed with some other bits) is intended to be written to the LPUART Global register.

Comment: grep the whole source tree for this macro usage.

Comment: NXP divides its documentation into 2 files: a data sheet and a reference manual. You want to look at the reference manual.  It goes into great details on every register.

Comment: The macro does a bit shift and masks out potential other bits to get the `GLOBAL_RST` flag at the expected bit position for some configuration register. (You might get unexpected results if you use macro argument values other then 0 or 1. I would implement this in a different way.) My guess is that you have to use bitwise OR to combine it with other flags/values in the register to define the register value. Example: `uint32_t lpuart_register_value = LPUART_GLOBAL_RST(0) | LPUART_FOO(1) | LPUART_BAR(0);` or directly assign this to the HW register (probably defined like a variable or structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify how NXP sets up its defines in the SDK:

Pretty much every register gets a "set", a bitmask, and a shift define for every field in the register. The shift isn't really useful generally, but it's used in their "set" define.

If you just want to set (or clear) a field in a register, it's sufficient to just OR/NAND the mask into the register eg

```
 LPUART0->GLOBAL |= LPUART_GLOBAL_RST_MASK;  // set
 LPUART0->GLOBAL &= ~LPUART_GLOBAL_RST_MASK; // clear
```

Sometimes, it's more useful to use the "set" macro, typically when the data encompasses more than one bit. It's "safer" in that it won't let you set bits that you aren't supposed to.

```
 LPUART0->GLOBAL |= LPUART_GLOBAL_RST(1);     // Sets the value of the reset field to 1.
 LPUART0->GLOBAL |= LPUART_GLOBAL_RST(0xFF);  // Still just sets the value of the reset field to 1 and doesn't break anything else.
```

It's also useful to use the full set macro when you're setting all bits of a register at once. That way, you can explicitly set all bits to 1 or zero.

For example, here's some code that sets up sets up my ADC0 CFG1 register on a KL27:

```
    ADC0->CFG1 = ADC_CFG1_ADLPC( 0 )  |
             ADC_CFG1_ADIV( 3 )   |
             ADC_CFG1_ADLSMP_MASK |
             ADC_CFG1_MODE( 1 )   |
             ADC_CFG1_ADICLK( 0 );
```

[image]

Without needing to think about things, I'm setting ADIV to 3 (both bits set), ADLSMP to 1, and the mode to 1, while explicitly setting all other bits to 0. Note that the "set" macros whose value is 0 do nothing, and are merely shown for better readability.